# Graceful recovery from policy file load failure

Tags: apache-flex, security, sockets

First off: This is not another question about how to load a policy file.

I have an app in development that connects to a socket server, gets the policy file and works just dandy. However, when the socket server is down for whatever reason, I need to gracefully fallback to an alternative method of getting messages from the server (polling, basically).

This is not a problem, except for one thing:

```
Error: Request for resource at xmlsocket://[ip]:4770 by requestor from http://[ip]/cooking/Client.swf has failed because the server cannot be reached.
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to catch this. I have these event listeners on my socket:

```
addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
```

SecurityErrorEvent is what you might think fires, but it doesn't. The docs say it fires for these reasons:

1. Local untrusted SWF files may not communicate with the Internet. You can work around this limitation by reclassifying the file as local-with-networking or as trusted.
2. You cannot specify a socket port
   higher than 65535.
3. In the HTML page that contains the
   SWF content, the allowNetworking
   parameter of the object and embed
   tags is set to "none".

So none of those apply. It appears what I really want to catch is the failure of the policy file to load, but even doing an explicit Security.loadPolicyFile() won't help, since that load is deferred to the first socket request AND doesn't fire any events.

For completeness, I also surrounded the call to connect() with a try{}catch (e:*){}, no result.

There's got to be a way to sort this. Any ideas? I simply need a way to tell when the connection has failed because of networking issues and try an alternate path.

EDIT: Despite my previous tests and the docs, it appears SecurityErrorEvent does fire - only it does it about 20 seconds after the load fails, so it's not obvious. I guess that's as immediate as I'm going to get from Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to retry connecting :)

```
private function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
  e.stopPropagation();
  ++this.retryCount;
  if( this.retryCount >= 12 ){
    this.connectTimer.stop();
    this.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'TIMIEDOUT' ) );
  }else{
    this.err = 'IO-ERROR-EVENT - ' + e.text + '\r\nAttempting to reconnect';
  }
}
```